# How to use 'Action Bar Style Generator' with ActionBarSherlock?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

I don't understand what I've to do in my project when I've downloaded my .zip in the awesome tool http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

I've all resources, but I think I have to do some modifications in my styles.xml & themes.xml in addition to put theses resources in my project ?

My resource suffix is *_test

Thanks a lot for your answers :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> but I think I have to do some modifications in my styles.xml & themes.xml in addition to put theses resources in my project ?

That depends on what you have done so far, prior to using the generator.

The generator should have given you `styles_test.xml` files, probably in `res/values/` and `res/values-v14/`. These will define a theme, `Theme.Test`.

If presently your theme for your application (or individual activities) in the manifest is a standard ActionBarSherlock theme (e.g., `Theme.Sherlock`), just change it to reference your newly-generated `Theme.Test`, and you should be good to go.

If, on the other hand, you have already been working on a custom theme for other things, then you will need to decide for yourself how best to blend in what is found in `Theme.Test` into your own custom theme. For example, you might have your custom theme set `Theme.Test` as the parent theme.

Comment: Indeed, I put all the times all resources except values-v14/ folder, and it was my problem !